# Trying to make a modal dialog appear with jQuery and PHP

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a email button, that when clicked, should pop up a modal jQuery UI dialog that shows a button for emailing yourself. My code is here:

```
<input type="button" value="Email to me" onClick="$("#emailModal").dialog({title:'Email It Along',height:300,width:350,modal:true,resizable:false});"/>
```

And here is `#emailModal`:

```
<div id="emailModal">
<p><input type="button" value="Email to me" onClick="$('#emailPost').submit()" id="emailJQButton"/></p>
</div>
```

However, when I click on the button, nothing happens, and no dialog pops up. I've looked through all my code and can't find the problem. Any help?

**Edit:**
Found the problem but I have a further one:

```
if($_SESSION["loggedIn"] == 1)
                        {
                            echo "<form action='php/emailPost.php' method='POST' class='inline' id='emailPost'>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' value='" . $_SESSION["email"] . "' name='emailAddress'>";
                            echo "<input type='button' value='Email To Me' onClick='$(\"#emailPost\").submit();$(\"#emailModal\").dialog('close');'/>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='passedCoupID' value='" . $coupID . "'/>";
                            echo "</form>";
                            echo "<h3>Or</h3>";
                            echo "<form action='php/emailPost.php' method='POST' class='inline' id='emailPost2'>";
                            echo "<input type='text' value='Enter an Email' name='emailAddress' style='display: inline-block;'>";
                            echo "<input type='button' value='Email' onClick='$(\"#emailPost2\").submit();$(\"#emailModal\").dialog('close');'/>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='passedCoupID' value='" . $coupID . "'/>";
                            echo "</form>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "<form action='php/emailPost.php' method='POST' class='inline' id='emailPost2'>";
                            echo "<input type='text' value='Enter an Email' name='emailAddress' style='display: inline-block;'>";
                            echo "<input type='button' value='Email' onClick='$(\"#emailPost2\").submit();$(\"#emailModal\").dialog('close');'/>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='passedCoupID' value='" . $coupID . "'/>";
                            echo "</form>";
                        }
```

I'm displaying it with PHP echo now, and I know that should require some special escaping rules. Neither inline function works though, not the emailPost submit nor the dialog close.

Comment: You could try installing Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) and stepping through the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `"` in attributes if they are quoted with `"`, too. Use `'#emailModal'` instead of `"#emailModal"`.

However, the proper solution would be this:

```
<input type="button" value="Email to me" id="emailButton" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#emailButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#emailModal").dialog({title:'Email It Along', height:300, width:350, modal:true, resizable:false});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code (apostrophes)

```
onClick="$("#emailModal").
```

should be

```
onClick="$('#emailModal').
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `onClick` for the button, you have double quotes inside double quotes.

```
onClick="$("#emailModal").dialog({...
```

I suggest you don't use `onClick` and you use jQuery to bind the events instead.

```
<input type="button" value="Email to me" id="sendEmail" />

<div id="emailModal">
  <p><input type="button" value="Email to me" id="emailJQButton"/></p>
</div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#emailModal").dialog({
      title: 'Email It Along',
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      resizable: false,
      autoOpen: false
    });

    $('#sendEmail').click(function(){
      $("#emailModal").dialog('open');
    });

    $('#emailJQButton').click(function(){
      $('#emailPost').submit();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OTOH i think you should use

```
<input type="button" value="Email to me" onClick="$('#emailModal').dialog({title:'Email It Along',height:300,width:350,modal:true,resizable:false});"/>
```

**EDIT**

Or as ThiefMaster said try using something in the lines of

```
$(function(){
    $('#myinput').click(function(){
        $('#emailModal').dialog({title:'Email It Along',height:300,width:350,modal:true,resizable:false})
    });
});
```